# Can I code using Swift on Mavericks?

Tags: macos, xcode

Is is possible to code using Swift on OS X Mavericks? I found [the manual](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11) on iBooks but that's as far as I can get right now.

Comment: James, I'm going to make some minor edits to this so it doesn't mention pre-release OS X versions but stays true to what you're asking to do.

Comment: Not only can you, you probably should. If your job is to write code, depending on a beta OS and a beta IDE might be more instability than what you propose here.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To code using Swift you'll need Xcode 6.

Xcode 6 beta is compatible with Mavericks 10.9.3 and upwards so **yes** it is possible to write Swift code in Mavericks!

**NB**: As of July 11, Xcode 6 beta is available freely on [Apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/).

- [Where can I download Xcode (n) Beta?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/132842/)

Comment: no sir. it was a friends suggestion hence am tryng to clairfy :D

Comment: Note that as of July 11, Apple is allowing downloads of the Xcode beta for free;  no requirements other than an email address and EULA agreement.

Comment: @HarshaMV please provide reference

Comment: @MaRco85 this was in the first release. not any more. u can now.

Comment: @HarshaMV please provide asap to correct the answer cause it's against stack overflow policies as not updated.

Comment: @MaRco85 deleted the comment

Answer (score 8):

You can write iOS apps with Swift in Xcode 6 Beta. Go to the Apple Dev center to get the newest Xcode. I would keep my stable version of Xcode installed as the beta may be a little buggy, but it will get you started till a stable version gets release which will probably this fall.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the only way to use Xcode for Swift programming is through the Beta version of Xcode 6. However, in order to download the Beta you must join (or be a member of) the iOS Developer Program or the Mac Developer Program.

Answer (score 1):

The final XCode 6 has released and is available in the App Store. (to be precise, I'm talking about `Version 6.0.1 (6A317)`).
I was surprised to see that (in contrast to XCode 6 beta) it does support Swift *only for iOS!*
(Look at [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPNyh.png), this is what I see when trying to create a Swift playground; also, Swift can be choosed as a language for iOS project, but not for OS X project)