# Can I download xcode 6 without dev account?

Tags: xcode

I don't want to download iOS 8 or so, but I want to start learning Swift without paying 100$. So, is there a way to download xcode 6?

Comment: I'm going to put this on hold temporarily this until it can be edited to make clear if this is about running software on pre-release OS X versions or if the Xcode 6 runs on Mavericks.

Comment: You can put this on hold, it's about pre-release, didn't know that I can't ask that.

Comment: Also see [Can I code using swift on Mavericks](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/132652/can-i-code-using-swift-on-mavericks) I bet if you watch on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) I bet there will be some good nuts/bolts about how to assemble a toolchain for Swift language and Cocoa programming before long.

Comment: Xcode 6 runs on Mavericks 10.9.3 and upwards

Answer (score 6):

Apple won't provide freely a beta of Xcode. Only Yosemite is available for non dev-members. Xcode 6 will be free once it reached a release version.

Though, you'll be able to find XCode on non legal downloading site...

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to look uo something. I don't want to use it to enjoy myself or so, but I can't afford 100$ to pay for learning a code. i can't seem to find one yet though.

Comment: [Yosemite is not available for non-dev members](http://picpaste.com/pics/Screen_Shot_2014-06-02_at_6.42.10_PM-OFZTP2Nj.1401749282.jpg)

Comment: Yes it is. You have to redeem a code : https://appleseed.apple.com/sp/betaprogram