# Where can I download Xcode (n) Beta?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I want to start developing in Swift. I already own an apple developer account, yet am struggling to download Xcode (n) beta.

How can I do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does struggling to download mean?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Go to https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action
2. If you are still not Update Program License Agreement, don't forget to  do it:
   [image]
3. In the top left, select iOS 8 Beta
4. Scroll down and search for **Xcode 6 beta**

Comment: That's exactly what I had to do :)

Answer (score 16):

If you are an Apple Developer for iOS or Mac OS X, which is [$99 a year](https://developer.apple.com/programs/), go to the Xcode page and scroll down to [Xcode 6](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/).

If you are already signed into the [Apple developer portal](https://developer.apple.com), you can [download the Xcode](https://developer.apple.com) disk image.

Comment: I'm on that page, and signed into iOS developer center, but there are no links on the page you linked to for downloading Xcode 6. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @CharlieS you will need to click on `iOS 8 Beta` first

Comment: Fun fact: if you have a university development account, it won't let you download XCode 6 (or any beta software for that matter). I don't know why they do it.

Comment: If you have a university account, you can’t participate in the forums either, if recall.

Comment: That's not very fun.

Answer (score 8):

If you are in the *paid* developer program you can download the beta from:
https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

If you have a free developer account, you cannot download the beta.

Comment: The free developer account restriction has been lifted. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/132843/5472

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action
2. Log in
3. Look right above the **Resources for iOS 7** header you'll see the **iOS 8 beta** pill.  Or just search for the text **iOS 8 beta** on the page.
4. Click on **iOS 8 beta** pill
5. Heed the **Read Me Before Downloading** warning
6. Click on **Download Xcode**
7. Profit

Comment: Aren't you missing a step between 6 and 7?

Comment: @waldrumpus, Nah, he'll just clone Flappy Bird.

Comment: @Klikerko  https://github.com/fullstackio/FlappySwift

Answer (score 5):

This has changed. The better place to download Xcode 6 Beta (as of Beta 3), is the [Apple Swift resources page](https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources/).

Comment: Login is still required.

Comment: @GeorgeGarside Yes but you don't need the paid developer account now

Answer (score 4):

Xcode 6 beta is available to anyone that signs up for a free developer account at https://developer.apple.com/programs/which-program/ and scroll to the bottom of the page.

Paid developers get distribution and code signing certificates, but you can start with Swift and the beta Xcode 6 for free. More details are on the developer news and the Apple swift blog:

- https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=07112014a
- https://developer.apple.com/swift/
- https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources

The last link with resources has books, guides, sample code and links to the latest Xcode betas as well as WWDC videos covering the language and using it with Cocoa and other Apple API.

Comment: I think the links have changed however the information is correct. I am downloading Xcode 6 beta 3 as we speak and I have the free dev account. Try this link https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources/

Comment: @styfle thanks. Feel free to edit things like that on the answer going forward :)

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded it from here:
https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/